# How do you refer to the judgment day of a single person?

Tags: word-request

How do you refer to the judgment day of a single person? What do you call the day where a man is judged by God (christian God) and God deliberates whether he is to be sent to hell or not. Is it called Judgment Day or something else?

Comment: Judgment Day is  the same for everyone, according to those believe this.

Comment: Judgement day is only for the wicked the rest are OK; "There will be a group of people who have rejected Christ and chosen a life without God. They will be resurrected to face their judgement and acknowledge for themselves that God is just (Romans 14:11)......Do not marvel at this; for the hour is coming in which all who are in the graves will hear His voice and come forth—those who have done good, to the resurrection of life, and those who have done evil, to the resurrection of condemnation.” John 5:28-29

Comment: Possibly "comeuppance" or "karma" are close, but lack the specific religious context you're looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Judgement Day* generally refers to the [*Last Judgment*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Judgment), or *Day of Reckoning*, or *Doomsday*, or however you want to translate *Yom haDin* (יום הדין).

When individuals die, they are judged on the spot, in what Catholics refer to as *particular judgement*.

> **particular judgement**
>
> *Roman Catholic Church*
>
> The judgement of each individual soul immediately upon its separation from the body at death; opposed to general judgement.

[Lexico - Particular Judgement](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/particular_judgement)

---

Christians who are not Catholic don't have any such belief - thanks to Brad for the reminder - so they may have no word or phrase to describe it, unless they're referring to the Catholic concept.

And as long as I'm adding editorial notes, I'll mention that I suspect the term *particular judgement* may not be especially well known by non-Catholic English speakers.  I, a non-Christian native English speaker, was familiar with the concept from pop culture, but had to look up the proper term, which I had probably never heard before.

I would guess that most Americans also don't know the proper term.  As I suggested in a comment, in a casual context, we'd probably describe the event.

Comment: is there a more natural way to refer to that day?

Comment: @Sayaman, in what context?  If you want to be exact, this is the phrase to use.  If you're making a joke or something, you'd talk about "meeting St. Peter at the pearly gates."

Comment: I'm sorry, but most Americans don't know the term?? That's really misguided. Furthermore, it is not only a Catholic idea...

Answer (score 2):

2nd Edition; **There are two answers**

**Popular concept**, and the **Religious concept**.

---

**Popular concept** Ref [DiffSense](https://diffsense.com/diff/day%20of%20reckoning/judgement%20day)

*Apocalypse*; There does not appear to be any particular uniform Christian belief of judgement separately to that arising at the time of the Apocalypse; an imminent cosmic cataclysm in which God destroys the ruling powers of evil and raises the righteous to life in a messianic kingdom.

*Day of reckoning* as a noun (religion): The final and eternal judgment by God of all nations; Final Judgment.

*Judgement day* as a noun (Christianity, Islam, Judaism): The Last Judgment, Final Judgment, final trial of all humankind, both the living and dead by God expected to take place at the end of the world, when each is rewarded or punished according to his or her merits.

**Note**; Spelling According to [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/judgment-day?q=Judgment%20day) ***Judgment Day***

---

**Religious concept**

Q. How do you refer to the judgment day of a single person?

A. *There is no simple judgment day of a single person*

Q. What do you call the day where a man is judged by God (***Christian God***) and God deliberates whether he is to be sent to hell or not. Is it called Judgment Day or something else?

A. Every single person who has died all throughout Earth’s history will be woken up by **a call of Jesus** but only **the wicked will face a day of Judgement** not everyone.

---

***There is a misunderstanding in your idea, relating to Christian beliefs***, of what happens when a person dies. Which is not really surprising as what happens is defined in the *Bible* but each sect of Christianity must put their own spin on this to attract members to "My Church Inc". There is really only one battlefield where the different denominations can fight, "The Arena OF Eternal Life" and what it is going to cost each of us to gain entrance.

---

Most of the ***Christian, or non Orthodox Christian, beliefs relate to what St Paul said "*Jesus would decide*"***. If you want to relate to what God says then you should relate to the Original book and I would suggest the Jews have more  expertise in relation to that.

Also many commonly referred to **events are not actually biblical but derived by the Catholic Church**. For example "Particular Judgement" did not arrive till the 16th century, so I am not quite sure what happens to all those who died during the previous millennia. Also Everyone who has died will wake when Jesus calls but according to St Paul only those who believe in Jesus can enter into the Kingdom of heaven. So where Adam, Abraham and the likes, who have never heard the teachings of Jesus, will end up I am not sure. An exert from *The Apocalypse of Peter*, a text written during the early to mid second century, again relates to ***the judgment of non believers***, but in this case of a more Jewish rooted belief  "The lawlessness"

3. And then God will come unto my faithful ones who hunger and thirst and are afflicted and purify their souls in this life; and ***he will judge the sons of lawlessness.***

---

The Bible does not teach that we have an immortal soul that immediately goes to heaven when we die.

**What Happens When You Die? You Sleep until you are woken up by the call of Jesus.**

Comment: Just because a particular bit of theology was developed at a certain time doesn't mean it only applies from that point forward. And not to get into a theology debate on a wholly inappropriate site, but Luke 23:43 seems to directly contradict your conclusion.

Comment: Bible and Biblical take caps in English, usually.

Comment: @Lambie Agreed in the case "are not actually **biblical"** Correctly or incorrectly, I did it deliberately,  as it is "not biblical" as opposed to "Biblical".  However I do stand corrected with a small font bible earlier on. My apologise.

Comment: @OrangeDog I actually totally agree with you, in fact that is the point, of  my brief foray., I like you not wishing to get into a debate on religious theory. The many contractions and totally impractical statements found in the New Testament.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers explained, Judgement Day day refers to the Last Judgement (for Catholics and Protestants) which will happen at an unspecified time in the future for everyone at the same time.

Juhasz answer is the first time I've heard "particular judgement."  I've never heard this word, and I doubt my catholic friends have either.  Most protestant lay people assume you'll be judged when you die.

Since it's not nice to talk about people dying, the most common phrases I've heard is "The day he meets God/Jesus" or "The day he meets his maker."  At least in America, the belief they you are judged the day you die is widespread.  Even if the listener doesn't agree with the theology, they'll know what you mean.  It's also not a commonly contentious point of theology, so you're very unlikely to offend people.

Answer (score 1):

While technically Judgement Day is for people and the **Day of [Reckoning](http://reckonyourself.com/resources.htm?action=definition)** is for [nations](https://diffsense.com/diff/day%20of%20reckoning/judgement%20day), in American English we commonly speak of a person's individual Day of Reckoning, and it implies a more personal act such as the OP is looking for.

Although such a use may be theologically incorrect, "It was his Day of Reckoning" will be easily recognized as a time of personal judgement either literally at a person's death, or metaphorically any time they are called to account for their behavior.

Comment: Even by your own reference you are incorrect, "There is no judgement day for Christians" there is only judgement for the wicked, unfortunately this by default means non Christians.  *Lets just ignore the fact Jesus was a Jew not a Christian*. The myth of Judgement day for Christians is a Hollywood fiction and a collection plate motivation. Quote, "When God sees a person’s faith, an exchange takes place in that person’s account with God. God places the believer’s guilt on Jesus, whose death paid the penalty for the believer’s sin and allowed God to cancel the believer’s debt of guilt".

Comment: Therefore as such "Day of Reckoning" does not answer the OP question as it it not when The Christian God decides the fate of an individual. In the case of Christians it has been decided already.

Comment: @Brad OP is asking on ELL Stack, not Christianity.  I am assuming that they are more interested in what expression would be used and understood rather than what is correct doctrine.  YMMV.

Comment: Yes you may well be correct but you can never be quite sure with our OP'S. To be honest we, the community, are marking this question up. But it is a bad question, an interesting one maybe but it is incorrect. The question is incorrect as it's  based on an incorrect idea No doubt the OP is trying to relate Christianity to another religion. Answers are opinion based on religious grounds and  due to the lack of and the conflict of source material. To be honest many of our statements may be incorrect based on what source we use and we could all be right or all be wrong.